# One job advertisement per company per ad block shown

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I suggest that SO show at most one job proposal per company in a given advertisement at a time, rather than potentially showing many different positions for a single company in a given ad.

> [image]

Comment: I get the Crossover issue,  but i don't get the 1 job per proposal per company. What if a company is in the midst of an expansion. Should we really say "sorry, only 1 listing". If Crossover is really that bad, then SO should stand up and say no.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't think Sergei meant one listing _period,_ just show only one per company in the ad in the screenshot at a time.

Comment: Lucky for Crossover, they are monopolizing the list.

Comment: `Lisp software architect` what year is this

Comment: @Qix and the lisp software architect needs to know C++ but not Lisp.  Strange!

Answer (score 3):

I'll have to give this some thought. I don't think it's *obvious* that limiting to one company per ad is the correct solution. We have other ad units (company page ads) which are *designed* to show multiple jobs by the same company. If you actually liked the company, seeing a variety from them might be a good thing.

It seems like what you're annoyed at here is the company itself. So a better solution might be to give you the opportunity to tell us you don't want to see jobs from that company at all. It's something we want to do, we just haven't figured out the right UI for it yet. It might be added to the box you get after you click the "X" dismiss button on a job ad.

Longer-term we'd like these sorts of preferences to flow in both directions. If you dismiss a job in an ad, you shouldn't see it (by default) on the job board. If you dismiss it on the job board, you shouldn't see it in an ad. We do a little bit of this sort of thing now, but it could be a lot better.

Comment: Would definitely be an improvement to be able to "not see" particular companies, how about in "match preferences" an option such as "companies I would prefer not to work for"

Answer (score -1):

This seems tricky to get right.  What if the jobs being offered are a Software Engineer and a DevOps position.  Show the wrong one for the current user and they won't click on it but they might have been interested in the unshown position.

Or for agencies who want to use SO to advertise the "one ad per company rule" will be annoying.  Showing one ad per agency is bad because the positions will be completely unrelated (placed at different companies).

Perhaps the logic can be improved to show you ads that are more relevant (and perhaps a too similar criteria should take in to account the company).  Showing ads that are too similar to each other is bad because if you don't want to click on the first then you won't want to click on the second either (same company, same pay scale, same technology => only show one).

Comment: As long as the most relevant job is either reliably chosen or chosen the majority of the time non-deterministically, the first point shouldn't be too big a deal; if the right job doesn't show up on one occasion, it can just wait until another page load. SO doesn't allow recruiters/headhunters to advertise; all jobs advertised must be to work at the company putting up the ad. So your second point shouldn't be an issue. (If it hurts Crossover, well, too bad; they're just skating by on technicalities as it is.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I'm surprised to hear about the recruiters as I've seen them before.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/hays-plc.  That even makes it clear that they are working as recruiters.

Comment: Bit misremembered here. All postings have to identify the actual company being worked for, but an agency can post on behalf of their clients. http://talent.stackoverflow.com/house-rules: "One position and one location per job listing.
Multiple positions need to go into multiple job listings. If you are a recruiting firm posting on behalf of your client, then your client needs to be named as the employer and your role in the process needs to be explained."